# PHP - properly setting session for login page

Tags: php, session, pdo, session-variables

On my website i log users in perfectly but i noticed that when a user is logged out, they can simply hit backspace and be re-logged in or even just put the file name in the URL. I found a lot questions on this matter but some are very vague with little steps and others are very outdated. I basically want to give the user a token for the session, that i have generated and set to the database already, and that token will be seen in the URL as GET request for security but i do not know how to go about this. Here is my code for the login page and upload page

PHP Login Page

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

        try{

            // new php data object
            $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
            //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception 
            $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

        }

        $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE username = :username");

        $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

        if($result = $stmt->fetch()){

            if(password_verify($password, $result['password'])){

                $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
                $stmtToken = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM token_table WHERE token = :token");
                $stmtToken->execute(array(':token'=>$token));
                if($rowToken = $stmtToken->fetch()){

                    die("Error, Please try again");
                }

                $userid = $result['user_id'];
                $email = $result['email'];
                $time = time();
                $stmtSendToken = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO token_table set timestamp=?, user_id=?, token=?");
                $stmtSendToken->execute(array($time, $userid, $token));

                $stmtUpdate = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET isDev = true WHERE user_id =?");
                $stmtUpdate->execute(array($userid));

                $_SESSION['id'] = $userid;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['timestamp'] = $time;

                header("Location: developerUpload.php");
            }

        }else{

            die("Username OR Password is incorrect! Please try again");
        }



    }else{

        die("Values Missing!");
    }

}



?>
```

PHP upload page after logging in

```
<?php
session_start();

if(array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)){

        //set the session id equal to the cookie
        $_SESSION['id']= $_COOKIE['id'];
    }
    if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)){

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        echo "Welcome To the Developer Side ".$username."!";

        echo "<br><br><button><a href='developerLogin.php?logout=1'>Log Out</a></button></br></br>";

        if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0){

            $target = "devFiles/";

            $target_file = addslashes(trim($target . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])));

                // Check file size not > 500Mb
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000000){

        echo "Files Cannot be bigger than 500MB";
        exit;
    }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){

            try{

        // new php data object
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception 
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

    }
            $dev_file = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
            $file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name']));
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $email = $_SESSION['email'];
            $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
            $time = $_SESSION['timestamp'];


                $stmt = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO developerfiles set user_id=?, username=?, email=?, dev_file=?, file_name=?, timestamp=?");

                if(!$stmt->execute(array($userid, $username, $email, $dev_file, $file_name, $time))){

                    die("Error");
                }else{

                    echo "Thank you for Submiting!";
                }

    }
        }


    }else {

        header("Location: developerLogin.php");
    }


?>
```

Comment: I do not think it's secure to do that, everyone can use History in browser to get the token and logging in without password

Comment: Not safe to store the token in the database? Or use session tokens? Because facebook and other websites do it

Comment: Do you destroy user's session on logout?

Comment: Yes i want to do that as well

Answer (score -1):

In your upload file you did not check the session again.
So every one could login into your upload file, only create an `$_SESSSION['id']='1'` and a `$_COOKIE['id']='1'` and your logged in (also if the id did not exists).
And one tipp: Set an Hash (md5, uniqueid,...) or somthing like that in your _SESSION (from your database, insted of an id) or every one could login as every user, only changing the _SESSION id.

The other thing is, you did not set an `_COOKIE` in your hole script, but in your upload file you check if the `_COOKIE` is set, or remove the _COOKIE check in your upload file

So add an `setcookie()` to your login page too, to work with your current file.
And add a second SQL request to your upload file, like:

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
if(!is_numeric($id) or $id<1) $id = 0; // a little bit of "security".
"SELECT * WHERE `id`='$id'";
if($sql_request => true){
 // write the script
} else {
 // you are not logged in
}
```

To destroy the _SESSION (logout) set the _SESSION like this `$_SESSION['id']='empty'; unset($_SESSION['id']);` so no one could use the back button to login back.

So there is no need to do it unsave with an token in your URL.

Comment: You should learn about prepared statements, before you start giving people advice about "security".

Comment: @tereško how would you go about this :D I am very lost